# ${}$ Dirac delta potential

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, potential, schroedinger-equation, dirac-delta-distributions

We know that the number of bound states for an attractive delta potential is one. If so what will the number of bound states for a particle in a repulsive delta potential?
If $V(x)= +a \cdot \delta(x)$?

Comment: How could a repulsive force bind anything?

Answer (score 4):

There is no bound state for the positive Dirac potential. Look at the derivation of the bound state in e.g. [these lecture notes](https://www.reed.edu/physics/courses/Physics342/html/page2/files/Lecture.11.pdf). Formula (11.15) for the wave function of the bound state $$\Phi(x,t)=\frac{\sqrt{am}}{\hbar}e^{-\frac{am|x|}{\hbar^2} + i \frac{a^2 m t}{2\hbar^3} }$$ is derived without assuming $a>0$. But if a negative $a$ is inserted in the formula it becomes un-normalisable because of the first spatial term inside the exponential is now positive, implying a growing amplitude away from the spike. Hence demanding normalisation implies no bound state in this case.

Comment: Thank you sir. Answer is really helpful